# ¿Error al ejecutar $ npm start?

Tags: npm, terminal, línea-de-comandos

No he podido encontrar una solución en la web, aparecen problemas similares pero no el mismo. ¿Alguien puede echarme una mano?

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-72-generic<br/>
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"<br/>
npm ERR! node v8.10.0<br/>
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2<br/>
npm ERR! path /home/dsantos/package.json<br/>
npm ERR! code ENOENT<br/>
npm ERR! errno -2<br/>
npm ERR! syscall open<br/>


npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dsantos/package.json'<br/>

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dsantos/package.json'<br/>

npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself<br/>

npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.<br/>

npm ERR! enoent <br/>


npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:<br/>

npm ERR!     /home/dsantos/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Podrias ejecutar ls en el directorio y mostrarnos el resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se logra ver en los logs adjunto, se está intentando ejecutar `npm start` en el directorio `/home/dsantos`, en lugar del directorio de la aplicación que se quiere ejecutar o el folder del proyecto donde pueda encontrar fácilmente el archivo **package.json**.

Cuando se ejecuta `npm start`, lo que quiere decir es ejecuta el script marcado como *start* dentro del *package.json*. [Aquí se puede consultar la documentación](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start).

e.g.

```
{
    "name": "your-app",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "ng serve"
    }
}
```

En este ejemplo al ejecutar `npm start` iniciaría el servidor de angular (*ng serve*).

Así que para resolver el problema bastaría moverse al directorio de la aplicación que se requiere ejecutar.

Comment: Igual me arroja error, tienes razon en lo que dices, ya que deja de mostrar varios errores pero mira los que se quedan. Te dejo el error como una respuesta porque como comentario se ve muy feo.

Comment: Considero que se ha resuelto la pregunta original y que es más conveniente realizar otra pregunta para ese error especifico, así más usuarios pueden verse beneficiados llegando a la solución de la segunda pregunta (publicada como respuesta).

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

Mira! igual se ven estos errores. Pero varios efectivamente eran por lo que tu dices.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE<br/>
npm ERR! syscall spawn<br/>
npm ERR! file sh<br/>
npm ERR! errno ENOENT<br/>
npm ERR! react-example@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`<br/>
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT<br/>
npm ERR! <br/>
npm ERR! Failed at the react-example@0.1.0 start script.<br/>
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.<br/>
<br/>
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:<br/>
npm ERR!     /home/dsantos/.npm/_logs/2019-12-06T19_33_02_404Z-debug.log<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instala el cli `npm install -g @angular/cli` esta es la herramienta para ejecutar esos comandos. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

quizás se trate de un problema de límite de observadores (`watchers limit`), y también tengas el siguiente error:

```
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/folder_project'
```

Sí ese es el caso, intenta ejecutar los siguientes comandos en la consola:

```
$ echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -p
```